# SELinux prevents NRPE to run properly in RHEL 6.8: Could not complete SSL handshake with

Tags: selinux, rhel6, nrpe

I downloaded **nrpe-3.2.0.tar.gz** and **nagios-plugins-2.2.1.tar.gz**, extracted, compiled and installed in a RHEL 6.8 64-bit box.

It runs fine when SELinux status is **Permissive**, but it does not work in **Enforcing** mode.

I have run a lot of times

```
grep -e nrpe -e nagios /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M nrpe
semodule -i nrpe.pp
```

but I always get the same error message from the Nagios server:

```
check_nrpe  -H 10.252.1.212
CHECK_NRPE: Error - Could not complete SSL handshake.
```

and in the `nrpe.log` of the node:

```
[1505198565] is_an_allowed_host (AF_INET): host is in allowed host list!
[1505198565] Host address is in allowed_hosts
[1505198565] Error: (!log_opts) Could not complete SSL handshake with 10.252.1.134: 5
[1505198565] Connection from 10.252.1.134 closed.
```

I'm aware of the [RHEL errata](https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2012:0780) mentioned in [this other question](https://serverfault.com/questions/269520/selinux-prevents-nagios-plugins-from-running-on-rhel6) but the selinux release installed in my box are:

```
selinux-policy-targeted-3.7.19-292.el6.noarch
selinux-policy-3.7.19-292.el6.noarch
```

Can you help me?

P.D: I'm a novice in the use of SELinux.

Comment: is there anything in the audit.log now?

Comment: @Tux_DEV_NULL, No. There is no new message in audit.log, otherwise the `audit2allow -m` command would report any difference between the current module and the `denied` found in audit.log.

Comment: Then this might not be selinux. When it works in permissive mode, what do you see in check_nrpe output? Did you try with -n option in both cases (with and without selinux)?